# How do I get selected date with YUI calendar if no javascript fallback

Tags: calendar, yui, accessibility

Please be gentle, I am perplexed I can't figure this out...
I was told to use the YUI library because it is the most accessible library and that it provided fallback when JavaScript was not enabled. I cannot figure out how I would get the selected date for a calendar widget when JavaScript is not enabled. Nothing seems to be posting on submit.I tried to bind to an input box instead of a div but it just ignored the binding.
If JavaScript is enabled I can just push the selected value to an input box.
Is this widget the exception to the rule since it binds to a div or is there a secret way to find out what the user has selected with JavaScript not enabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many YUI widgets are designed to enhance existing HTML, and fall back to something useful even if JS is turned off or broken. For example, a YUI TabView's core markup is a list of links; if you break JS, you still have those working links to click on.

But YUI Calendar is not a form element in and of itself -- instead you should think of it as an *enhancer* for form elements. Your instinct to attach it to an input element is the correct one. The good news is that the YUI gallery has a popup calendar, built on top of the base calendar, which is designed to bind to  elements and appears below the element when the user focuses there.

This is a classic progressive enhancement scenario. If the user has JS, they get a fancy calendar. If not, they can still fill out the plain input field -- no harm done.